# How do you find the number of contiguous subarrays of size $k$ in a given array?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, algorithms, data-structure

For example: Given the array $[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$ where $N$ is the length of the array and $k$ is the subarray size. Here $N = 9$ and given $k = 5$, we find that $N-k+1$ contiguous subarrays of size $k$ can be found. How can we prove $N-k+1$ as the number of contiguous subarrays of size $k$? I'm sure it is intuitive, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: HINT: If a subarray of length $k$ starts at position $m$, at what position does it end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looking at the answer for a general value of $k$, let's look at specific examples.

First of all, how many subarrays of length one are there? The answer to this question is $n$. Why? Because we can choose any of the $n$ elements to be in our array.

Next, how many subarrays of length two are there? The answer to this question is $n - 1$. Why? Because we can choose any of the $n$ elements *except* for the last element to be the "start" of the array (and the element directly after it will also be included). Note that we cannot "start" the array at the last element since there's no element to include afterward.

Continuing with the exact same reasoning, we can see that the answer for subarrays of length $k$ must be $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ since we're able to "start" the array anywhere except for the last $k - 1$ positions.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm sorry I meant contiguous subarrays, does the proof still hold?

Comment: Yes, my answer is supposed to be for contiguous subarrays. You are correct that we cannot choose any of the $n$ elements when considering subarrays of size $k$. I stated this in my answer. The last paragraph of my answer computes the answer for a subarray of size $k$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! Is there any way to write a proof for this though?

Comment: I think it might be a little bit overkill to write a formal proof for this. If you really want to, you can fix $N$ and induct on $k$. Do you know how to apply induction?

Comment: No, I don't see how we could prove this using induction, please let me know if you do.